# how to change listBox item font colour from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I have tried to access ListBox items properties like this:

```
mylistBox.Items[0]
```

and then to set foreground property but for unknow to me reason i cant access it this way. Can i even do this using code behind - and if yes - how?

Comment: Do you want to change `Foreground` for all items?

Comment: No, I need to change one, particular item in a listbox. Not all items

Answer (score 2):

Implement ItemTemplate and bind your Brush to Foreground property.

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your binding object and notify on MyColorBrush value change.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" Foreground="{Binding MyColorBrush}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```